# Notification from a service

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display a simple notification when a C2DM message is received. Services provide to UI but still run on the main thread. I've seen people claim you can create and display Notifications from a service.

```
 @Override
public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.w("Messsage","Message Received");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String payload = (String) extras.get("test");
        createNotification(context,payload);





    }
}

private void createNotification(Context context, String message){
    NotificationManager notificationmanager =  (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.default1,message,System.currentTimeMillis());


    notificationmanager.notify(0,notification);
}
```

}

```
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService    [stp.chrome@gmail.com]
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   contentView required: pkg=com.upmc id=0 notification=Notification(contentView=null vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x0)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1331)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:299)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:124)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:103)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at com.upmc.C2DMReceiver.createNotification(C2DMReceiver.java:80)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at com.upmc.C2DMReceiver.onMessage(C2DMReceiver.java:66)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver.onHandleIntent(C2DMBaseReceiver.java:108)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 15:39:13.580: E/AndroidRuntime(11603):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I have no idea why this exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, the exception is thrown because you create a notification which has no view object referenced to it (contentView attribute is set to null) . You have to call [setLatestEventInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#setLatestEventInfo%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) before showing the notification.

Second, the constructor you're using is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#Notification%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20long%29). Please use the class [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) for creating notifications. If you support Android < API level 11, you can use the class [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) from the support library.

Third, yes it is possible to create notifications from a running service.

Comment: setLatestEventInfo is also deprecated.  Use the builder to set content elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the Notification documentation. Content View is required if you don't called the setLatestEventInfo() method.