# Android notification never shown

Tags: android, notifications

I want to create notification from service. Here my code:

```
    private void showNotification(String text) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, PocketSaverActivity.class), 0);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentTitle("the title").setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    notificationManager.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher, notification);
}
```

But this code returns me a warning `04-08 20:25:49.030: W/NotificationManager(1670): notify: id corrupted: sent 12345, got back 0`
 and doesn't show. I don't know what is the problem. Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057250/notification-from-a-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("the title")
    .setContentText(text)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setAutoCancel(true);
```

You need to add `.build()` to the end, like so:

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("the title")
    .setContentText(text)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();
```

Also, `Notification notification = builder.getNotification();` is not necessary, just use the chained, built notification.

You can see a more generic example in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)